# How to show flash message only in current page for particular time only using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

When I upload a resume, it shows the resume uploaded successfully. But this message remains when i shift to the next page.

But when I shift to another page for the third time this flash message disappears.

The message also disappears when the page is refreshed .

Can you help me on how can i make a flash message disappear when I shift to the next page and also it should only show for a particular time.

```
fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl( json, file ).then(function(res){
                if( res.success !== undefined ){
                    FlashService.Error(res.message,  true);
                } else {
                    if (res.json.response.statuscode==0) {
                        console.log(res.json.response);

                        if( type === "photo" ) {
                            $cookieStore.put('photoid', res.json.response.photoid);
                        } else {
                            $cookieStore.put('resumeid', res.json.response.resumeid);
                        }

                        FlashService.Success( ( $scope.capitalizeFirstLetter( type ) +" upload successfully" ),true);
                    } else {
                        FlashService.Error(res.json.response.statusmessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You can use the $destroy event in a scope to remove the flash mesage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my above issue by using below line in my code in my controller.

```
FlashService.Success( ( $scope.capitalizeFirstLetter( type ) +" upload successfully" ),false);
```

I used 'false' instead of 'true'.

**flash.service.js :**

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('FlashService', FlashService);

    FlashService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
    function FlashService($rootScope) {
        var service = {};

        service.Success = Success;
        service.Error = Error;

        initService();

        return service;

        function initService() {
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
                clearFlashMessage();
            });

            function clearFlashMessage() {
                var flash = $rootScope.flash;
                if (flash) {
                    if (!flash.keepAfterLocationChange) {
                        delete $rootScope.flash;
                    } else {
                        // only keep for a single location change
                        flash.keepAfterLocationChange = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function Success(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
            $rootScope.flash = {
                message: message,
                type: 'success', 
                keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
            };
        }

        function Error(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
            $rootScope.flash = {
                message: message,
                type: 'error',
                keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
            };
        }
    }
```